# Can I use the Jar API in a web start app?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I would love to see if I can get this app to work with JWS.  It started as a client app, with a couple of folders of user data files.  The user can goof with those folders - even add data files from the net.  ... Enter JWS...

This code worked with a JAR file not using JWS, but it cannot find the JAR file when using JWS.  (jarName = "myjar.jar")

```
    static public ArrayList<String> getJarFileList(Dir d, ExtFilter ext) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jarName); 
        JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(fis);

        JarEntry jarEntry = null;
        do {
            jarEntry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
            if (jarEntry != null) {
                String fileName = jarEntry.getName();
                if(d == null || fileName.startsWith(d.toString())) {
                    if(ext == null || ext.accept(null, fileName))
                        list.add(fileName);
                }
            }
        } while (jarEntry != null);
        jis.close();            
    } catch (IOException ioe) { }

    return list;
}
```

In the end, I want to be able to get a list of data files in the JAR and save them into a local folder I create on the client.  If possible, I would like to not have to know exactly the names of all the files in the JAR that I will have to get - hence getJarFileList(for a particular directory and filename extension).

If there is no direct way, perhaps the simplest thing for me to do is make the app go to the web site and copy data files to the client?  Any suggestions on what API to use for moving these files is also appreciated.

TIA -
Mark

got a fix... will post it in 2 hours...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things, and I have achieved some success!

The first (unsuccessful) attempt was to take my (default/install) user data directories w/files, and put them in a jar file inside of the main jar file.  Then, I successfully got a JarInputStream of the inner jar file upon an InputStream returned by getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myinnerjar.jar").  I ran into trouble when trying to get individual files/streams out of that.

In the second (successful) attempt, I put the data files jar on the server side, and went with a URL to it in my JWS app.  url.openStream() worked, and then just in.read() and out.write(). This is working from a JAR on my machine as well as when in Java Web Start.  I am able to create local folders full of data files in my JWS app.

The only other thing to deal with is where the local files go (I gave relative output paths), and on Windows 7, they went to various places... Hee hee.  I think for various platforms, I will root these folders in the user's home dir.

TIA-
Mark